# Dashed \longleftrightarrow

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, arrows

I want to write a short causal path diagram like so:
`$Z \longleftrightarrow X \to Y$`

Except I would like the `\longleftrightarrow` to be dashed, in much the same way that there is a `\dashrightarrow` and `\dashleftarrow` (although ideally with the same arrow heads as in `\longleftrightarrow`, not the slightly smaller ones that `\dashrightarrow` seems to use)

Is there such a symbol? I have been searching about but currently drawing a blank.

Comment: My guess is that you'd be better off drawing the arrows with tikz or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tikz` solution. Define a macro `\longdashleftrightarrow` (or some suitable shorter name) that draws an arrow of length `1.75em` (approximate length of `\longleftrightarrow`). Loading the `arrows.meta` library will make the arrowheads the same size and shape as `\to`.

You can adjust the dash pattern if you like. Also, there is an optional argument if you want a different length arrow, e.g., `\longdashleftrightarrow[1cm]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\longdashleftrightarrow}[1][1.75em]{\mathrel{
    \tikz[baseline]{\draw[dash pattern=on .25em off .1 em,<->](0,.58ex)--(#1,.58ex)}}}

\begin{document}

$Z \longleftrightarrow X \to Y$

$Z \longdashleftrightarrow X \to Y$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.